# Actualizar columna con datos de otra base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente update donde digo que la columna peso se actualice con los datos de la columna peso pero de la otra base de datos y donde le digo que sea igual a el lote de la otra bd y al animal

```
UPDATE [2_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes 
SET peso = (SELECT peso FROM [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes) 
WHERE  codlote = (SELECT codlote FROM [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes) AND 
animal =  (SELECT animal FROM [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes)
```

Pero me sale el siguiente mensaje
**Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.**

Esto a que se debe puede ser que haya mas filas en una que la otra, pero si ya estoy haciendo la comparación de que sea igual el codlote y al animal y las dos base de datos son iguales solo necestio actualizar el campo peso de una por la otra, como ven en la img los datos son diferentes es actualizarlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que tus tres subconsultas son independientes entre sí y no están relacionadas con el `UPDATE`. Si efectivamente estás usando SQL Server, puedes usar `FROM` y `JOIN` para relacionar las tablas y actualizar con los valores correspondientes.

```
UPDATE ml2
SET peso = ml1.peso
FROM [2_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes AS ml2
JOIN [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes AS ml1 ON ml2.codlote = ml1.codlote
                                       AND ml2.animal  = ml1.animal;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría realizando un JOIN entre las tablas de ambas bases, validando las condiciones mencionadas.

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.peso = B.peso
FROM [2_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes AS A
    INNER JOIN [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes AS B
                                            ON  A.codlote   = B.codlote AND
                                                A.animal    = B.animal
```